# Конструктор, прилетает undefined

Tags: javascript

Полагаю что вся беда в этой строке "Car.call(this, carObj);" а именно в "carObj". Поскольку у конструктора нет расписанных параметров "model, color, year", а всего один "carObj" бо решил попробовать сделать с одним параметром в конструкторе для закрепления знаний, его и запихнул в метод call() после this вместо тех трех, а видимо в то время когда должны подставляться параметры из конструктора Car, в него еще не поступил аргумент который указан в new Car(), хотя может ошибаюсь о причине и ее цепочке. Если возможно, то с небольшим обьяснением. П.С. js изучаю

```js
function Car(carObj) {
  this.model = carObj.model;
  this.color = carObj.color;
  this.year = carObj.year;
}

function SportCar(sportCarObj) {
  Car.call(this, carObj);
  this.engine = sportCarObj.engine;
  this.distance = sportCarObj.distance;
}


SportCar.prototype = new Car();
SportCar.prototype.constructor = SportCar;

Car.prototype.air = 'Air Conditioning';

Car.prototype.drive = function() {
  console.log(this.model + ' едет куда то .......');
};
Car.prototype.music = function() {
  console.log(this.model + ' added music system');
};

SportCar.prototype.camera = function() {
  console.log(this.model + ' has automatic Camera');
};

let hondaObj = {
  "model": "Honda",
  "color": "red",
  "year": 2016
};
let bmwObj = {
  "model": "BMW",
  "color": "yellow",
  "year": 1998
};
let audiObj = {
  "model": "Audi",
  "color": "white",
  "year": 2019
};


let honda = new Car(hondaObj);
let bmw = new Car(bmwObj);
let audi = new Car(audiObj);

let ferrariObj = {
  "model": "Ferrari",
  "color": "red",
  "year": 1968,
  "engine": 6,
  "dist": 700
};
let lambaObj = {
  "model": "Lamborgini",
  "color": "blue",
  "year": 2019,
  "engine": 7,
  "dist": 650
};
let ferrari = new SportCar(ferrariObj);
let lamba = new SportCar(lambaObj);

honda.drive();

ferrari.camera();
lamba.music();

if (honda instanceof Car) {
  console.log('honda - Машина');
}
if (honda instanceof SportCar) {
  console.log('honda - Спортивная машина');
}

if (lamba instanceof Car) {
  console.log('lamba - Машина');
}

if (lamba instanceof SportCar) {
  console.log('lamba - Спортивная машина');
}
```

Comment: покажи где у тебя объявлена переменная carObj внутри `function SportCar(sportCarObj) {`

Comment: @Grundy, получается нигде, видимо я немного не верно понял как заимствуются эти свойства, вернее с какого участка именно, как тогда позаимствовать 3 свойства у Car() с помощью Car.call() ? т.е. получается первым идет аргумент this, а вот после него я уже не могу написать так - Car.call(this, model, color, year) как это было в старом коде

Comment: надо просто передавать параметр который у тебя уже есть:sportCarObj

Comment: что то не вьеду, явно имелось ввиду не так Car.call(this, sportCarObj);

Comment: именно так и имелось ввиду

Comment: тоже самое пишет, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined

Comment: `SportCar.prototype = new Car();` покажи  в этом коде объект, который ты передаешь в конструктор `Car`

Comment: `SportCar.prototype = new Car(this);`, так теперь работает, благодарю :)

Comment: `new Car(this);` - плохое решение потому что `this` в этом случае - `window`, а если будет где-то `"use strict" - то опять `undefined`. Лучше посмотри как сделано в вопросе дубликате

Comment: Изучил тот пост, убрал `new Car(this);` и вместе с ним `SportCar.prototype.constructor = SportCar;`. Поставил `Object.create(Car.prototype, {остальное}`, все стало хорошо, спасибо. В статье также было указано что в целом это плохой пример как у меня было изначально, я его вычитал в книге "Фримен Э., Робсон Э. - Изучаем программирование на JavaScript (Head First O'Reilly) - 2015" :(((

Comment: Скорее несколько устаревший